# As$\ n \to \infty$, can a transcendental function$\ f\left(1+ \frac{1}{n}\right)$ to the power of$\ n$ tend to a rational power of$\ e$?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, proof-writing, rational-numbers, transcendental-numbers

Let$\ f(n)$ be a transcendental function$\ \ne e^{g(n)}$, for any function$\ g(n)$. Does$$\ \lim_{n \to \infty} \left(f\left(1+ \frac{1}{n}\right)\right)^n =e^{ -k} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \left(1 - \frac{k}{n}\right)^n $$ imply the irrationality of$\ k$? I have no means to think whether this has a positive or negative answer, but I do think the number$\ k$ at issue (which obviously has other properties) is irrational, hence the question.

Comment: Could you define what is a transcendetal funcion in your question? It seems you are using a very concrete one?

Comment: To quote wikipedia: "A transcendental function is a function that does not satisfy a polynomial equation whose coefficients are themselves roots of polynomials" Exp, sin, cos are such functions for instance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Example.**
$f(x) = 1/\Gamma(x)$ is certainly a transcendental function.  It has zeros, so it is not exp of an entire function.  But your value $k$ is Euler's constant $\gamma$.  Which has not yet been proved irrational...

**more**
If $c$ is any nonzero constant, then $\sin(cx)$ is a transcendental function.  But your value $k$ is then $c \cot c$ if my computations are right.  And certainly there is some constant $c \approx -4.493$ so that $c \cot c = 1$.

Answer (score 2):

$$f(x) = {e}^{-k(x-1)}$$

This function should be transcendental and satisfy the conditions you've shown, but $k$ can be rational.

Comment: You're right, I should have specified that$\ f$ isn't$\ exp$. I've made the edit.

Comment: @Numberlover: In this example, f isn't exp.

Comment: @JonasMeyer I see what you say. I really meant that$\ f(n) \ne e^{g(n)}$.

Comment: That rules out most examples in a way, or are you saying you want examples with zeroes?

Comment: @JonasMeyer Well, what I want is either at least an example (any) to the claim, with my conditions, or the proof that there are no examples at all.

Answer (score 1):

Well if $f(1) = 1$ and $f$ is differentiable at $1$, then $\lim (f(1+1/n))^n = \exp(f'(1))$.

Now, there is absolutely no relationship whatsoever between differentiable functions whose derivative at $1$ is rational and "transcendental functions" (whatever that means), or wether $f$ is of the form $\exp(g)$ (or equivalently, functions with no zeros).